# Ordem dos resumos LaTeX

Tags: latex

Estou precisando de ajuda com a ordem dos resumos no meu artigo. Quero que o "RESUMO" venha primeiro que o "ABSTRACT". O mesmo com as palavras-chave, "PALAVRAS-CHAVE" primeiro e depois "KEYWORDS". Estou usando o modelo "sigconf" do ACM (link para os arquivos zip abaixo). O código que estou usando pra colocar os dois resumos também está abaixo.

[LATEX (Version 1.65)](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart-master.zip)

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage[brazil,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\andify\authors}
  {\add@brazil@keywords\andify\authors}
  {}{}
\def\brazilkeywords#1{%
  \gdef\add@brazil@keywords{%
    \@specialsection{Palavras-chave}#1\par
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract in English.

\begin{otherlanguage}{brazil}
\section*{\abstractname}
Este é o resumo em português
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Abc, def}
\brazilkeywords{Ghi, jkl}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Você tem muito mais chances de encontrar uma resposta no [tex.se] (se você entender inglês, é claro) ;)

Comment: Olá @fernandosavio, obrigado pela dica. Foi lá mesmo que consegui o código citado por mim acima, contudo preciso agora trocar a ordem e não consigo apenas trocando a ordem dos códigos e texto.

Comment: E lá ainda não me ajudaram nesse problema.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo sempre o modelo SBC e para mim é só trocar a sequencia no código. Veja se funciona.

```
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{otherlanguage}{brazil}
\section*{\abstractname}
Este é o resumo em português
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract in English.

\brazilkeywords{Ghi, jkl}
\keywords{Abc, def}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Olá Andrey, obrigado pela ajuda, mas já tentei trocar a ordem e mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: Olá, em qual dos arquivos você trocou ?

Comment: Testei com meu modelo SBC e teve um arquivo específico que troquei a ordem e deu certo. Abri seu modelo, mas não sei quais arquivos você está utilizando.

Comment: Estou usando o sample-sigconf.tex.

Comment: O arquivo fica localizado na pasta samples.